# EC2 can't access S3 file

Tags: django, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, access-denied

I have a very strange error on my website. I keep getting this Django error:

> Attempted access to
>   'http:/***.s3.amazonaws.com/media/banderas/Cambodia-flag.png'
>   denied.

But when I access that file directly from my admin panel, it works fine. It fails only when the main page wants to access that file.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What permissions are set? If you're accessing the Url for the image whilst logged in via the admin panel then you have full permissions to view anything/delete anything etc.

If the image url is used in a web site you need to make sure that the S3 object has an "Everyone" View/Download permission set. What happens if you access the image url without being logged in to the admin panel - just put it into the browser address bar?

Comment: Files accessed from the admin console are accessed via a signed url if the file is private.

Comment: Found it. Periods in bucket name caused that. I updated the `boto` version and everything worked :)